# Match single item from a group or items separated by comma in different orders

Tags: regex, pcre

I have such regex:

`/A|B|A,B|B,A/`

Which is the best way to refactor it using groups?

Comment: Longer alternatives should come first: [`B,A|A,B|A|B`](https://regex101.com/r/jT8jO1/1). Why use groups?

Comment: `/([AB])(,(?!\1)[AB])?/`?

Comment: @Biffen A B were probably placeholders for longer patterns
OP please provide the whole thing

Comment: @onreachable Yes. Is that a problem?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm trying to avoid specifying  A and B twice.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: @AlexanderLebedev `/([AB](,|$))+/`, then? If repetitions aren't allowed, perhaps you could check that externally?

Comment: If you want to avoid specifying them twice, you have 2 wayouts: 1) if it is PCRE (or Ruby), use subroutines, 2) else, use blocks to build a pattern dynamically. See [`(A),(B)|(?2),(?1)|(?1)|(?2)`](https://regex101.com/r/jT8jO1/2) What is the regex flavor?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks! It works.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using PCRE, you can just wrap the subpatterns you need to repeat with *capturing groups*, and then just recurse them with `(?n)` syntax (subroutine calls):

```
(A),(B)|(?2),(?1)|(?1)|(?2)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT8jO1/2)

Here, `(A)` captures `A` into Group 1 and `(B)` captures `B` into Group 2, so, in order to use these subpatterns later in the pattern, just use `(?1)` to match the first subpattern and `(?2)` to repeat the second one.

You can also use named capture groups:

```
(?<first>A),(?<second>B)|(?&second),(?&first)|(?&first)|(?&second)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT8jO1/3)

Comment: Саша, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку раз уж моё решение сработало.

Answer (score 0):

The longest first alternation approach can be replaced by refactoring the regex.
A software tool that can refactor even complex regex, can be found here  http://regexformat.com
As a general tip, the list should be sorted for better outcomes.

Before

`A|B|A,B|B,A`

After

`A(?:,B)?|B(?:,A)?`

https://regex101.com/r/PXBhJw/1